# Deny insert/delete for all users in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, insert, delete

In our database we have about 20 users, that is used be some program (and users are added with this program). Now there was new requirement to use 2 database and do not allow delete data from one database.

What would be easiest way to deny insert/delete access for some tables (not all)? All users have `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be confusing if you granted someone `db_datawriter` and then denied them `delete` rights.  So if you can, remove them from the `db_datawriter` and then grant them the rights they need:

```
create role role_MyApp
grant select, insert on Table1 to role_MyApp
...
exec sp_adduserrole 'role_MyApp, 'User1'
```

Comment: With new role it probably will be easier to administrate users, than modify rights for each. Probably will do that and especially thanks for code :)

Comment: Nice example with the application roles.

Answer (score 0):

Deny all modifying operations to public db role or if it is possible - set the DB into read-only mode

**or**

place tables that shoupd be unmodified onto read-only filegroup

Comment: I set "insert" permission on table for database role [public] to "deny". But it's still possible to insert new record in that table. User is only member of "db_datareader", "db_datawriter". There's few tables, that user should be ablo to modify, so it's not possible to set read-only mode.

Comment: Try to avoid mixing various paradoxial permissions involving public role. And - updated answer